# How to center align inside table* and minipage?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align, minipage

Centering or centred box doesn't work. The mintage has to stay in the `table*` environment. `\hrule` separates the text beneath.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centerline{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{align}
  {x=2\cos\left(\beta\right)}\\
  {F_{3}(\lambda)=\sin \lambda}\\
  {\gamma_{0}(\lambda)=1+h\left(\lambda\right)+k \left(\lambda\right)+k^2 \left(\lambda\right)+k^3 \left(\lambda\right)+k^2 \left(\lambda\right)+k^5 \left(\lambda\right)}
\end{align}
\medskip
\hrule
\end{minipage}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you writing a two-column document?

Comment: @Bernard yes, two-column article.

Comment: a table is essentially already a minipage so you do not need `\centerline` or `minipage` here. (`\centerline` isn't really a latex command anyway and shouldn't be used at all). Just use `align` it centers by default

Comment: unrelated but you are using `align` without specifying any alignment perhaps you intended to use `gather` ?  in `{x=2\cos\left(\beta\right)}` both the `{}` and the `\left\right` adversely affect the spacing, should be `x&=2\cos(\beta)\\ `

Comment: If you want to center-set the equations, you should be using a `gather` environment, not an `align` environment.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I have used this environment before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want one of the following (it wasn't clear if you wanted alignment or not as you used `align` but specified no alignment points) so I used `gather` for no alignment or `align` for aligned =, both center by defailt so no `\centerline` or `\centering` is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{gather}
  x=2\cos(\beta)\\
  F_{3}(\lambda)=\sin \lambda\\
  \gamma_{0}(\lambda)=1+h(\lambda)+k (\lambda)+k^2 (\lambda)+k^3 (\lambda)+k^2 (\lambda)+k^5 (\lambda)
\end{gather}

\medskip
\hrule
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}
\begin{align}
  x&=2\cos(\beta)\\
  F_{3}(\lambda)&=\sin \lambda\\
  \gamma_{0}(\lambda)&=1+h(\lambda)+k (\lambda)+k^2 (\lambda)+k^3 (\lambda)+k^2 (\lambda)+k^5 (\lambda)
\end{align}

\medskip
\hrule
\end{table*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David :)

Comment: The purpose of the `minipage` with width less than `\textwidth` *may* have been an attempt to limit the width of the line drawn by `\hrule` to, well, the width of the `minipage`.

Comment: @Mico I considered that but took a calculated guess that it wasn't:-) anyway if a shorter rule is needed using `\centering \rule{.9\textwidth}{.5pt}` would be the way.